# Best way to implement "Preview" functionality in asp .net Mvc3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using ASP.NET MVC. I would like to implement preview functionality to a form. i.e. I have a form with number of fields for example name, address etc.. Before the user submits the info, he/she can preview it as to how it will appear on the site.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will work for you or not, but you could [download the Orchard project](http://www.orchardproject.net/) and take a look at their preview implementation. I think you're going to have to save the "preview state" of the form as unpublished and then provide a way for the user to view the unpublished state of the form.